# Beginning Haskell: A project based....How to I construct a Vector from a (Double, Double)

Tags: haskell, parameterized-types

I'm working through the examples in "Beginning Haskell: A project based approach" and in Chapter 6 you write kMeans during which I pass in a [(Double,Double)] and convert them to vectors and life is good. It all works.

However, I'd like to create a vector in ghci after importing the Vector module and it all blows up.

```
Prelude Chapter6.TimeMachine> import Chapter6.Vector
Prelude Chapter6.Vector Chapter6.TimeMachine> toVector ((0,0) :: (Double, Double))

<interactive>:15:1:
    No instance for (Vectorizable (Double, Double) v0)
      arising from a use of `toVector'
    The type variable `v0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there is a potential instance available:
      instance Vectorizable (Double, Double) (Double, Double)
        -- Defined in `Chapter6.Vector'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Vectorizable (Double, Double) v0)
    In the expression: toVector ((0, 0) :: (Double, Double))
    In an equation for `it': it = toVector ((0, 0) :: (Double, Double))
```

I imagine this is all caused by the way Vector is defined, but I don't understand why. There is an instance instance Vectorizable (Double,Double) (Double,Double) already so I would expect toVector to handle input of (Double, Double). I'm certainly creating lists of (Double, Double) as the data I pass into kMeans and it calls toVector without problems, however the kMeans function has the following type signature which somehow resolves this issue:

```
-- kMeans takes input data and computes the centroids based off 
kMeans :: (Vector v, Vectorizable e v) => Int -> [e] -> [v]
kMeans numCentroids dataPoints = ...
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this. I've tried various incantations and not gotten anywhere.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, BangPatterns #-}

module Chapter6.Vector where
import Data.List

class (Ord v) => Vector v where
  distance :: v -> v -> Double
  centroid :: [v] -> v
  isUndefined :: v -> Bool    

instance Vector (Double, Double) where
  isUndefined (a,b) = isNaN a || isNaN b
  distance (a,b) (c,d) = sqrt $ (c-a)*(c-a) + (d-b)*(d-b)
  centroid vs = let baseVal = (0,0,0) :: (Int, Double, Double)
                    (n',x',y') = foldl' (\(!n,!x,!y) (x2,y2) -> (n+1,x+x2,y+y2)) baseVal vs
                in toVector (x' / fromIntegral n', y' / fromIntegral n')    

class Vector v => Vectorizable e v where
  toVector :: e -> v    

instance Vectorizable (Double,Double) (Double,Double) where
  toVector = id
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's look at your error:

```
No instance for (Vectorizable (Double, Double) v0)
  arising from a use of `toVector'
The type variable `v0' is ambiguous
```

GHCi knows that you're trying to convert a `(Double, Double)` to an instance of `Vector`, but it's not sure which one.

You could clear this up a couple ways.

Like the error says (`Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)` - "fixes" as in "fixes in place" not "repairs"), the simplest way is to tell it which one:

```
λ toVector ((0,0) :: (Double, Double)) :: (Double, Double)
(0.0,0.0)
```

The reason *why* this is ambiguous is that you've set up your `Vectorizable` type class to support many different instances, like:

```
instance Vector () where
  isUndefined () = True
  distance () () = 0.0
  centroid _ = ()

instance Vector Double where
  isUndefined = isNaN
  distance = (abs .) . subtract
  centroid = uncurry (/) . foldl' (\(!x,!n) y -> (x+y,n+1)) (0,0)

instance Vectorizable (Double,Double) () where
  toVector = const ()

instance Vectorizable (Double,Double) Double where
  toVector = fst
```

None of these are defined *yet*, but they could be, and the compiler doesn't want to guess for you in an ambiguous situation.

A solution to get rid of the ambiguity would to use either FunctionalDependencies (aka FunDeps) or TypeFamilies to make the output type dependent on the input type for Vectorizable:

e.g.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
-- ...
class Vector v => Vectorizable e v | e -> v where
  toVector :: e -> v
```

or

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleContexts #-}
-- ...
class Vector (Output e) => Vectorizable e where
  type Output e
  toVector :: e -> Output e

instance Vectorizable (Double,Double) where
  type Output (Double, Double) = (Double, Double)
  toVector = id
```

Now it suffices to specify your input type, since the other instances of `Vectorizable` given above are no longer legal:

```
λ toVector ((0,0) :: (Double, Double))
(0.0,0.0)
```

If you use `TypeFamilies`, you can make the relationship between the input and output bijective, so you could specify either the output type OR the input type

```
class (Output e ~ v, Input v ~ e, Vector v) => Vectorizable e v where
  type Input  v
  type Output e
  toVector :: e -> Output e

instance Vectorizable (Double,Double) (Double,Double) where
  type Input (Double, Double) = (Double, Double)
  type Output (Double, Double) = (Double, Double)
  toVector = id
```

gives:

```
λ (toVector (0,0)) :: (Double, Double)
(0.0,0.0)
λ toVector ((0,0) :: (Double, Double))
(0.0,0.0)
```

([thanks to this thread for the idea](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-January/053696.html))

Comment: Doh! It never occurred to me to constrain the input to (Double, Double) and the result to (Double, Double). Thanks!

Comment: Ah, this is all making sense now. In my larger program, where I never explicitly declare Vectors or Vectorizables as (Double, Double), it selects the only currently existing type when I pass in the data of type (Double, Double) and the instances exist so it works. But then when I try "let infinity = toVector (1/0,1/0)" inside a function it correctly gets worried that it may not be a valid Vector if the code is called where the data is a different type even though it would be valid with the current data set....